# Why LogisticRegression in Classify gives worse accuracy than result without PerformanceGoal Setting

Tags: machine-learning

Tested@Mathematica 11.1 on Windows

ModelA

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];

model=Classify[trainingData,Method->"LogisticRegression"];
cm=ClassifierMeasurements[model,testData]
cm@"Accuracy"
0.9261
```

ModelB

```
model=Classify[trainingData,Method->"LogisticRegression",PerformanceGoal->"Quality"];
cm=ClassifierMeasurements[model,testData]
cm@"Accuracy"
0.8964
```

"Quality"   maximize accuracy of the classifier.

```
model=Classify[trainingData,Method->"NearestNeighbors",PerformanceGoal->"Quality"];
cm=ClassifierMeasurements[model,testData]
cm@"Accuracy"
0.9659
```

Of course, glad to know the best parameters of Classify in LogisticRegression.

An interest thing: Quality is faster in some condition?

```
t1=SessionTime[];
model1=Classify[trainingData,Method->{"LogisticRegression","L2Regularization"->10},PerformanceGoal->"Quality"];
t2=SessionTime[];
t=t2-t1
80.5658897
t1=SessionTime[];
model2=Classify[trainingData,Method->{"LogisticRegression","L2Regularization"->10},PerformanceGoal->"TrainingSpeed"];
t2=SessionTime[];
t=t2-t1
166.8431739
```

Answer (score 2):

`The problem is PerformanceGoal->Quality will no only take effect on model-training parameters, but also the processor and other places`. 
Classify thinks without doing DimensionReduce is better, actually doing DimensionReduce is better.

```
model1=Classify[trainingData,FeatureExtractor->"NumericVector", Method->{"LogisticRegression","L2Regularization"->1},PerformanceGoal->"Quality"];
cm=ClassifierMeasurements[model1,testData];
cm@"Accuracy"
0.9262

model2=Classify[trainingData, Method->{"LogisticRegression","L2Regularization"->1},PerformanceGoal->"Quality"];
cm=ClassifierMeasurements[model2,testData];
cm@"Accuracy"
0.8969

model3=Classify[trainingData, Method->{"LogisticRegression","L2Regularization"->1}];
cm=ClassifierMeasurements[model3,testData];
cm@"Accuracy"
0.9261
```

Without DimensionReduce, the SessionTime is of course faster.

Actually `NumericVecotr` by default is doing Linear DimensionReduce, but here it keep the all dimension, so FeatureDimension is 784. But model3 doesn't do DimensionReduce in `Processor`.

```
KeyTake[Options[model1][[1]]["Models"][[1]],"FeatureNumber"]
<|FeatureNumber->784|>
KeyTake[Options[model2][[1]]["Models"][[1]],"FeatureNumber"]
<|FeatureNumber->784|>
 KeyTake[Options[model3][[1]]["Models"][[1]],"FeatureNumber"]
<|FeatureNumber->393|>

Options[model1][[1]]//Keys
{Basic,Input,Output,Combiner,Decision,Models,Log}
Options[model1][[1]]["Input"]
<|Preprocessor->ToMLDataset,Processor->ConformImage->ImageExtractNumericalVector->DimensionReduceNumericalVector->Standardize|>
Options[model2][[1]]["Input"]
<|Preprocessor->ToMLDataset,Processor->ImputeMissing->ConformImage->ImageExtractNumericalVector|>
Options[model3][[1]]["Input"]
<|Preprocessor->ToMLDataset,Processor->ImputeMissing->ConformImage->ImageExtractNumericalVector|>
```