# What does the value of Predict's "L2Regularization" correspond to?

Tags: fitting, machine-learning

What does the value supplied to the `Predict` `Method` option `"L2Regularization"` correspond to?

It does not seem to correspond to the conventional definition of $\lambda$ in the context of linear regression:

$$J(\mathbf{w})= \text{MSE}(\mathbf{w})+\lambda \mathbf{w}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{w}$$

For example

```
Predict[dmat -> y, Method->{"LinearRegression", "L2Regularization"->lambda}, PerformanceGoal->"Quality"]
```

does not produce the same predictions as a function generated from

```
Minimize[Mean[(dmat.w-y)^2] + lambda*w.w, w]
```

unless there's no regularization (`lambda = 0`).

Moreover, I can't see how to use `Predict` with `"L2Regularization"` to regularize only weights, but not bias (as is common on NN applications), as in

```
p=Prepend[w, b];
Minimize[Mean[(dmat.p-y)^2] + lambda*w.w, p]
```

where `dmat` is of the form `DesignMatrix[...,IncludeConstantBasis->True]`.

What value should I use for `"L2Regularization"` to match the effect of `lambda`? What options or other changes do I need to make to have `Predict` only regularize weights?

---

```
(* 
Generate things for an MWE 
*)
x = Partition[ RandomReal[{0,10},200], 2];  
f = #1-4#2+2*#1^3-50*#1 Sin[#1]Cos[#2]&;
y = MapThread[f ][Transpose@x]+RandomReal[{-400,400},Length@x];
basisFuncs = {1, x1, x2, x1^2, x2^2,  x1^4, x2^4, x1^5, x2^5,x1 Sin[x1]Cos[x2]};
weights = Symbol/@(ToString[StringForm["w``",#]]&/@Range[Length[basisFuncs]-1]);
bias = Symbol@"b";
params = Prepend[weights,bias];
dmat = DesignMatrix[MapThread[Append,{x, y}],basisFuncs, {x1, x2},IncludeConstantBasis->False];


(* 
With no regularization, the fit matches, though the Predict soluton has an extra, near-zero term that appears to be a side effect of the biases column in dmat.
*)

lambda=0;

Minimize[Mean[(dmat.params-y)^2] + lambda*weights.weights,params][[2]]

PredictorInformation[Predict[dmat->y,Method->{"LinearRegression","L2Regularization"-> lambda}, PerformanceGoal->"Quality"],"Function"]

PredictorInformation[Predict[Rest/@dmat->y,Method->{"LinearRegression","L2Regularization"-> lambda}, PerformanceGoal->"Quality"],"Function"]

(* 
With regularization, the fits don't match, even if all params are regularized.
*)

lambda=50; 

Minimize[Mean[(dmat.params-y)^2] + lambda*weights.weights,params][[2]]

PredictorInformation[Predict[dmat->y,Method->{"LinearRegression","L2Regularization"-> lambda}, PerformanceGoal->"Quality"],"Function"]

PredictorInformation[Predict[Rest/@dmat->y,Method->{"LinearRegression","L2Regularization"-> lambda}, PerformanceGoal->"Quality"],"Function"]

Minimize[Mean[(dmat.params-y)^2] + lambda*params.params,params][[2]]
```

Comment: What's your dataset？ it's very important.

Comment: I see this with *any* dataset. With `lambda = 0`, `Predict` and `Minimize` produce exactly the same results (as expected). With `lambda ≠ 0` `Predict` and `Minimize` give completely different results, suggesting that MMA's `"L2Regularization"` parameter is something distinct from $\lambda$. The question is: what is it?

Comment: lambda is a step in solve the solution, and if use different method, the result may be not the same.

Comment: @HyperGroups: Let me spell this out a bit: "L2 Regularization" has a meaning: generally when provided as an argument for an API it means something like "treat the provided value as $\lambda$ and incorporate L2-regularization into the prediction/learning/fit" or more precisely, add the second term in the equation above to the cost function, using the provided value as $\lambda$. But in MMA, `"L2Regularization"` clearly does not have this meaning. What does it mean?

Comment: `But in MMA, "L2Regularization" clearly does not have this meaning. How clearly?  ` Maybe  the L2Regularization works like Ridge or L2Regularizeation=f(lambda)?, but just the parameters scope is different from another implement? This is very normal in the ML packages.  I even cann't produce your result of `Minimize[Mean[(dmat.w-y)^2]+lambda*w.w,w]`   `General::stop: Further output of NMinimize::nnum will be suppressed during this calculation.`

Comment: @HyperGroups: Maybe someone else should have a go at answering this.

Comment: My judgement is right, I can reproduce SKLearn's Ridge in Mathematica's LinearRegression. The parameters scope is different, and there is an Normalize Manipulation.

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful answer if you provide a MWE.

Comment: @mmeent: MWE added.

Comment: I've tested your Minimize code, I can reproduce the result by Ridge with normalize=False, and alpha=1 corresponding to lambda=0.01. Bad thing is even we change object function, we can also get the same result when Lambda=0, so may be Predict's implement is a ghost method even with different object function

Comment: DimensionReducerFunction::mlincfttp: Incompatible variable type (NumericalVector) and variable value ({0.3444 (-4.93196+#1),0.341365 (-4.95324+#2),0.033035 (-32.7551+#3),<<4>>,0.0000397094 (-16783.2+#8),0.377135 (0.0494591 +#9)}). Without `PeformanceGoal`, do you have this error?`model=Predict[RandomReal[1,{10,1000}]->RandomReal[1,10],Method->{"LinearRegression"}];
PredictorInformation[model,"Function"]`

Comment: SEE 11.2's model,  Mathematica  use mean-cross-entropy for loss

Comment: @HyperGroups: For linear regression? No it does not (and why would it?). The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/method/LinearRegression.html) explicitly states that the loss is computed as: `Minimize[Total[(dmat.p-y)^2] + lambda*p.p, p]`

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a partly answer.

There are some questions in my understanding.

1. How can I reproduce the result of Predict by Minimize?
   If your question is that, another title is better.
2. Why lambda in Minimize doesn't gives the same result in Predict?
3. Does L2Regularization in Predict work like that in lambda in Minimize?

---

Answer for question1:
I cann't reproduce now, is it possible?

Answer for question3:
My answer is Yes now, `L2Regularization` is corresponding to `lambda`.

By tune parameters of L2, the weights decay and converge, though it's not like the case in Ridge, most values decay to nearly zero. `L2Regularization` is so-called `weight decay`, though in some context, we can say `L2Regularization` is Ridge[from context of PRML], but that will confuse someone and think `L2Regularization` should give the same result like Ridge Regression in SKLearn or other implementation like Minimize.

[image: parameters-weights]

Answer for question2:

1. Predict can use many methods to solve or train, like SVD, or Cholesky, SAG, and so on. L2 form is so called Ridge Regression, I've tested with SKLearn's Ridge, you may try it, and change the solver with sag and svd with alpha[Lambda/L2Reg] setting. And coefficients of model is not fixed and uniq, even the dataset is fixed. Bad thing is Mathematica maybe use ElasticNet or some other object functions or processing tricks with L2 norm.
2. There is no methods options, and detail method description in Minimize, so the results to compare is not rigid. When lambda is 0, they gives the same result, because they use the simplest OLSE least square methods.
3. Predict is going on a complex workflow, like encoding and data standardize and DimensionReduce and other manipulations. [one example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154644/6648)
   In this my example, I've spent some time to control some conditions, and find out this fact. Some methods like PCA will also need Standardize, sometimes ghost knows where and when Mathematica does it.
4. In different implements, the parameters scope is different and varying even with the same method. I've played with many ML packages, this is very normal in the ML packages. Maybe the L2Regularization works like this : L2Regularizeation=f(alpha)?, alpha is an lambda parameter in other implement.
5. Even in different object functions, we can get the same value when lambda=0.

I can reproduce SKLearn's Ridge in Mathematica by setting `L2Regularizeation` and `normalize` in some datasets. And I can reproduce Ridge in SKLearn by Minimize also.

Since OP edit the question, and add some Datasets and Minimize method to compare,
so I also edit something.

In different datasets, result will be not the same, that's why I say: 
What's your dataset？ it's very important in doing experiments, becuase Predict treat different data with different workflows.

- In my first dataset, Mathematica's Predict doing some Normalize manipulation, and I can reproduce the result by `SKLearn's Ridge` with parameters: `normalize=True` and `alpha`. In OP's dataset, I can only reproduce Minimize's result by `SKLearn's Ridge` with `normalize=False` and `alpha`, since OP use `Mean`, In Ridge we can use `Total`.

So, I'm sensitive to OP's thought: `But in MMA, "L2Regularization" clearly does not have this meaning.`How clearly?

---

code show the reason 3

```
    trainingset={1,2,3,4,5,6}->{2,3,5,8,9,7};
    linear=Predict[trainingset, Method->"LinearRegression"];
    Options[linear][[1]]["Models"][[1]]
```

[image]

---

I have some problem reproduce the OP's result of Minimize
Minimize[Mean[(dmat.w-y)^2]+lambda*w.w,w] General::stop: Further output of NMinimize::nnum will be suppressed during this calculation.

---

Reproduce Ridge result of SKLearn in Mathematica.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
reg=linear_model.Ridge(alpha=0.01, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
normalize=True, random_state=None, solver='svd', tol=0.001)

reg.fit(
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]], [0.0783993, 1.06691, 2.02407, 3.65314, 4.14089, 5.51513, 6.75203, 7.06544, 8.17167, 9.13125]
)
print(reg.coef_)
print(reg.intercept_)
[ 1.00262068]
-0.754520809274

model=Predict[dmat->y,Method->{"LinearRegression","L2Regularization"->.1},PerformanceGoal->"Quality"];
PredictorInformation[model,"Function"]
-0.754521 + 1.00262 #1 &
```

So here, as you see, alpha `0.01` in SKLearn's Ridge gives the same result with L2Regularization `0.1` in Mathematica.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here. Since the argument has a value, it must have some meaning. If you're just saying that sometimes `Predict` can produce results that don't match (the corresponding) `Minimize` results, that's not the problem here. With `lambda = 0` the results are exactly the same.

Comment: You got a down vote, I think, because you seem to be answering an eatery different question.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius OK, see edit, With lambda!=0, result can also be exactly the same.

Comment: Interesting. That's progress. So for `sklearn.linear_model.Ridge` I can get things to match by setting `alpha` to `len(dmat)` times $\lambda$ (and `intercept=True` and `normalize=False` and omitting the constant column from `dmat`, since, following deep learning practice, I'm not regularizing the bias). But I still can't get anything recognizable out of `Predict`. What's the source of the difference in the values. It's not merely 10x or multiplied by the sample size.

Comment: Also, it looks like `Predict` does some kid of normalization, which I can't unravel.

Comment: I wish the computations and model parameters weren't so obscured

Comment: @M.R. 11.2 gives more information about model, for example, Predict in LinearRegression use mean-cross-entropy